# Maintain Foreign Keys using Import/Export Wizard when creating a SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis, ssis-2012

I´m trying to create a SSIS package in SQL Server Management Studio using the Import/Export Wizard. I´m trying to copy the tables from an existing db to another one, but I´m getting errors because of the foreign keys (because the tables are created in a given order without taking care about the design).

How to add this foreign key to my package?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'
```

Then import your data

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT all'
```

Using that method I was able to import all the data in with no issues.